# Django celery run multiple workers with different queues

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

i try to configure three queues/workers for celery in django.

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('manually_task', Exchange('manually_task'), routing_key='manually_task'),
    Queue('periodically_task', Exchange('periodically_task'), routing_key='periodically_task'),
    Queue('firsttime_task', Exchange('firsttime_task'), routing_key='firsttime_task'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'api.tasks.manually_task': {
        'queue': 'manually_task',
        'routing_key': 'manually_task',
    },
    'api.tasks.periodically_task': {
        'queue': 'periodically_task',
        'routing_key': 'periodically_task',
    },
    'api.tasks.firsttime_task': {
        'queue': 'firsttime_task',
        'routing_key': 'firsttime_task',
    },
}
```

I have three tasks and every task should be have their own queue/worker.
My tasks look like this:

```
@shared_task
def manually_task(website_id):
    print("manually_task");
    website = Website.objects.get(pk=website_id)
    x = Proxy(website, "49152")
    x.startproxy()
    x = None


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour=19, minute=15)), ignore_result=True)
def periodically_task():
    websites = Website.objects.all()

    for website in websites:
        x = Proxy(website, "49153")
        x.startproxy()
        x = None


@shared_task
def firsttime_task(website_id):
    website = Website.objects.get(pk=website_id)
    x = Proxy(website, "49154")
    x.startproxy()
    x = None
```

Now for the first trial i start only one worker:

```
celery -A django-proj worker -Q manually_task -n manually_task
```

My problem is that the task not execute apparently, "manually_task" not printed.
Why its not working?

Comment: how did you invoke your tasks after the worker has been started?

Comment: In a view for example like this: `manually_task.delay(webseite.pk)`

Comment: With one worker and without `CELERY_QUEUES` and `CELERY_ROUTES` settings in the `settings.py` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the commments I suggest you should either provide queue name when you are calling a task from a view like `manually_task.apply_async((webseite.pk,), queue='manually_task')`, you  or add default queue named `celery` when you start the worker as in `celery -A django-proj worker -Q manually_task,celery`